# Selecting two date ranges from one table in SQL query is giving inflated numbers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to output two date ranges as columns grouped by a third in a single SQL query. The query works but is outputting significantly inflated numbers - is there something wrong with the query?

```
SELECT
  a.channel AS channel,
  SUM(b.sessions) AS 'thisYear',
 SUM(c.sessions) AS 'lastYear'
FROM overview a

LEFT JOIN overview b ON
 b.date= a.date
 AND b.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'

JOIN overview c ON
 c.date= a.date
 AND c.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'

WHERE a.channel!=""

group by a.channel;
```

The current output gives:

```
channel thisYear    lastYear
Direct  36891   118335
Organic Search  40231   98531
Paid Search 19962   NULL
Referral    14782   17266
Social  4228    23399
```

But those numbers are significantly above what they should be. 
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the ddl, and sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.channel AS channel,
sum(case when date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' then sessions else 0 end) AS 'thisYear',
...
FROM overview a
...
```

Even better, consider using year(datecolumn)=2015, unless you have performance issues(although I cannot imagine you'd have millions of rows in a table with those contents).